# Add sortable column for file size in media library Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have added a column for file size in the media library. Now I want to sort the files from largest to smallest (and the other way around) by clicking on the file size column title.

This is my code for adding the column in functions.php:

```
add_filter('manage_media_columns', 'td_media_columns_filesize');
/**
* Filter the Media list table columns to add a File Size column.
*
* @param array $posts_columns Existing array of columns displayed in the Media list table.
* @return array Amended array of columns to be displayed in the Media list table.
*/
function td_media_columns_filesize($posts_columns)
{
$posts_columns['filesize'] = __('File Size', 'text-domain');
return $posts_columns;
}
add_action('manage_media_custom_column', 'td_media_custom_column_filesize', 10, 2);
/**
* Display File Size custom column in the Media list table.
*
* @param string $column_name Name of the custom column.
* @param int $post_id Current Attachment ID.
*/
function td_media_custom_column_filesize($column_name, $post_id)
{
if ('filesize' !== $column_name) {
return;
}
$bytes = filesize(get_attached_file($post_id));
echo size_format($bytes, 2);
}
add_action('admin_print_styles-upload.php', 'td_filesize_column_filesize');

// Make column sortable
function add_column_sortable_file_size($columns)
{
$columns['filesize'] = 'filesize';
return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'add_column_sortable_file_size');
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same feature as you but with no luck so after all I've managed to write my own code.

The problem is that you can't sort columns without the pre_get_posts hook (you need to sort posts via query) and for that, you need to save file size as a meta field. Finally, you need to save it in the same format such as MB or KB for correct sorting.

And here is the code:

```
/* ------------------------------ MEDIA METADATA ------------------------------ */

// edits image meta data
add_action( 'add_attachment', 'my_edit_image_meta_data' );

function my_edit_image_meta_data( $post_ID ) {
    
    // checks if the uploaded file is an image
    if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {

        // finds the total file / image size
        $filesize = filesize( get_attached_file( $post_ID ) );

        // converts bits to mega bytes
        $filesize_convert = $filesize / 1024 / 1024;

        // converts number to format based on locale
        $filesize  = number_format_i18n( $filesize_convert, 3 );

        // creates new meta field with file size of an image
        update_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_filesize', $filesize );
    }
}

/* ------------------------------ MEDIA LIBRARY - COLUMNS ------------------------------ */

// creates new columns in media library
add_filter( 'manage_upload_columns', 'my_media_library_columns' );

function my_media_library_columns( $columns ) {
    $columns['filesize'] = __( 'File Size', 'text-domain' );
    
    return $columns;
}

// displays values for each image in specific columns
add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'my_media_library_sizes', 10, 2 );

function my_media_library_sizes( $column, $post_ID ) {
    if ( 'filesize' === $column ) {
        $filesize = get_post_meta( $post_ID, '_wp_attachment_image_filesize', true );

        echo $filesize . __( ' MB', 'text-domain' );
    }
}

// adds sortable function for new columns
add_filter( 'manage_upload_sortable_columns', 'my_media_library_sortable');

function my_media_library_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['filesize'] = 'filesize';

    return $columns;
}

// sets sorting for new columns
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_media_library_sizes_query' );

function my_media_library_sizes_query( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

    if ( 'filesize' == $orderby ) {

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_attachment_image_filesize',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_wp_attachment_image_filesize',
            ),
        );

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    }
}
```

I'm not a programmer, so I don't know if the code complies with WP coding standards, but this way it works well.

Comment: Thanks for this.  How do we add sot by ASC and DSC ?  at the moment it only sort low to high filesize, but not reverse.....

Comment: `$query->get( 'order' );` should return `asc` or `desc`. Use those to set the query sort order.